# Are there tests for conditionality?

Tags: syntax, semantics, conditionals

I am looking for ways to test whether something that (at least superficially) looks like a conditional actually has the necessary properties to qualify as one. Are there any such established semantic or syntactic tests for conditionality?
Any suggestions for possible properties that go along with conditionality I should look into are welcome as well.
I am thinking of something similar to, for example, how one can test negations using NPIs.

Comment: Negation is real and has real linguistic effects that can be detected. "Conditionality"  _per se_ is not a logical or syntactic feature; people sometimes ask questions here about "the _N_-th conditional", but that's just ESL jargon, not anything real in the language. Nobody so far has pointed to any semantic or syntactic tests that can be used to determine it, anyway.

Comment: A very big,in fact enormous, hole on your question is that not all conditionals exhibit conditionality and not all sentences, or pairs of sentences that exhibit conditionality are conditionals!!!

Comment: @jlawler I have pointed to semantic tests for it, but not of the normal semantic kind. (because conditionals aren't designed to fit in with our ideas about propositional logic etc)

Comment: Well, logic is just another mathematical theory, after all. Where did you point and what kind of tests?

Comment: Ping. I've read them, though I'll need to think about them, Is there a URL for the paper or proposal? Thanks, btw.

Comment: Sure. I'm always interested in latest thinking. It's sloppy and often correct. I figured this was diss material. No huhu. I got a whole shelf of dissertations with my name on the committee. You know the email, nu?

Comment: Yeah, got it. Thanks. Sorry not to have responded.